# registerMediaButtonEventReceiver Alternative setMediaButtonReceiver (PendingIntent mbr) not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

On press of headset need to bring my application to foreground for this I am Using registerMediaButtonEventReceiver() method, its working fine for below android os 5.1 devices. Now this method deprecated in API level 21. I am using mediasession.setMediaButtonReciever() to take the priority high but its not working.

```
AudioManager mAudioManager  = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        ComponentName mediaComponent = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), HeadsetReceiver.class.getName());
        mAudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(mediaComponent);
        mediaHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000L);
```

I am posting this for every 1 sec to get my priority app. I am using this code in 5.1 but on press of media button music starting. my app not getting any event to bring app to foreground. Thanks in Advance..

```
 MediaSession mSession =  new MediaSession(context,context.getPackageName());
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, HeadsetReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mSession.setMediaButtonReceiver(pintent);
        mSession.setActive(true);
        mediaHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000L);
```

Answer (score 3):

You also have to set a PlaybackState like this:

```
PlaybackState state = new PlaybackState.Builder()
                        .setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_FAST_FORWARD | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP)
                        .setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING, 0, 1, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime())
                        .build();
mSession.setPlaybackState(state);
```

Comment: I have seen that Google Play Music is able to receive headset button events and start playback even when the app is completely stopped and no background services are running. Any ideas how that's done? I'm asking here because I think that it could be achieved with MediaSession.setMediaButtonReceiver(), but if the app is not running, where will PlaybackState come into play?

Comment: The best practice is to release the media session when an app has finished performing playback or if the activity or service is being destroyed.
  
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSession.html#release()
  
I don't know how Google Play Music behave in this situation, but I noticed that GPM, but also the vendor's music application (like music app from LG), start a service at boot. I think that this service is the component that reacts to the media button press.
  
How do you check that no GPM background services are running?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I made sure that there were no components running by going to Apps > Downloaded  > Google Play Music > Force Stop, and then I pressed the headset button. It turned itself back on.

Comment: Ok, I noticed that when you "kill" an app with Force Stop if the app has a background android service this service is automatically restarted by the system (I don't know the exact behavior). I think that you are in this situation: Force stop of GPM > system automatically restarts the GPM service > button pressed > GPM reacts to the button

Comment: I'm tested GPM on both Google Android, and Cyanogenmod and found that they behave differently on these platforms. I will look further into it. Anyways, thanks for your replies!